# how to toggle a class on a div in react project for opening a mobile menu in mobile

Tags: reactjs, frontend

This is my current code which shows up a hamburger menu.

```
 <div className="navlines">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
 </div>
```

I want to add a new class "open" to the existing class "navlines". 
how can i do this in react. 
i just started learning react a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
<div className={"navlines " + (this.props.showHamburgerMenu ? 'open' : 'close')}>
```

When the value of showHamburgerMenu is true , the open class will be added otherwise close class will be there.

You can either use from props or from state i.e

```
<div className={"navlines " + (this.state.showHamburgerMenu ? 'open' : 'close')}>
```

Based on some click or a user action , you can set the state of showHamburgerMenu to true.

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jbh1qgzu/1/

Answer (score 1):

just do as in html.

```
<div className="navlines open">
```

if you want to do it dynamically based on some condition you can

```
var className = "navlines" + (condition ? " open" : "");
return (<div className={ className } />);
```